# { [Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5000]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku, deployd

What's wrong with the following Server.JS file?  We are trying to connect Deployd to Heroku and keep getting the following error.  We're using Nitrous, and I have configure the mongoDB port to 5000.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks a ton!

Server.JS

```
// require deployd
var deployd = require('deployd');

// configure database etc. 
var server = deployd({
  port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
  env: 'production',
  db: {
host: '0.0.0.0',
port: 5000,
name: 'database_name',
credentials: {
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
}
  }
});

// heroku requires these settings for sockets to work
server.sockets.server.set('transports', ["xhr-polling"]);

// start the server
server.listen();

// debug
server.on('listening', function() {
 console.log("Server is listening on port: " + process.env.PORT);
});

// Deployd requires this
server.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
  process.nextTick(function() { // Give the server a chance to return an error
process.exit();
  });
});
```

ERROR:

```
 db:error Error: Cannot open store: MongoError: server 0.0.0.0:5000 timed out
 at /home/nitrous/Find-Volunteerships/node_modules/deployd/lib/db.js:144:17
at /home/nitrous/Find-Volunteerships/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:330:20
at /home/nitrous/Find-Volunteerships/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:231:14
at null.<anonymous> (/home/nitrous/Find-Volunteerships/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:240:9)
at g (events.js:260:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at emit (events.js:172:7)
at /home/nitrous/Find-Volunteerships/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:493:23
at commandCallback (/home/nitrous/Find-Volunteerships/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1149:20)
at Callbacks.flushConnection (/home/nitrous/Find-Volunteerships/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:103:9)
at null.<anonymous> (/home/nitrous/Find-Volunteerships/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:408:24)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at emit (events.js:172:7)
at null.<anonymous> (/home/nitrous/Find-  Volunteerships/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:144:10)
at g (events.js:260:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) +0ms
  session:error Error removing old sessions: Database connection error +14ms
Unhandled rejection Database connection error
{ [Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5000]
 code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5000 }
```

Comment: You're trying to run two servers on the same port.  You can't do that

Comment: @SLaks  Thanks for the reply!  I changed one of the ports, but nothing happened.  Any idea?

Comment: Is something else using that port?

Comment: @SLaks  No, I even just added two new ports, but it won't work.  Just keep getting this error, MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:5001

Comment: There may be many solution but ultimately restarting my system works for me

Answer (score 1):

You are using same port for two servers.
You can kill one of them with that command

```
netstat -ano|findstr "PID :5000"
```

5000 is your port.